# Sign up User (insert into database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
TBL COL NAME                DATATYPE        ALLOW NULL

Subscriber_ID               int         Unchecked
Subscriber_Initial          varchar(5)  Unchecked
Subscriber_Name             varchar(50) Unchecked
Subscriber_Email            varchar(50) Unchecked
Subscriber_Group            varchar(20) Unchecked
Subscriber_Date             datetime    Unchecked
Subscriver_Active           bit         Unchecked
Subscriver_ActivateDate     datetime    Unchecked
Subscriver_DeactivateDate   datetime    Checked
```

Now When the user signed up, i need to check whether he's already existed in the table.

If not, Create a new record.

If so, check whether the user is active.

If not, activate it. update the activate date.

If so, return he's already signed up.

```
INSERT INTO 
[ZCustom_SubscriberList] 
(Subscriber_Initial,Subscriber_Name,Subscriber_Email,Subscriber_Group,Subscriber_Date) 
select @initial,@name,@email,'A1',@subdate 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [ZCustom_SubscriberList] WHERE Subscriber_Email=@email)
```

This is my code and it is working fine without Active column.  I am wondering how to add in the activate part.

Comment: why do you have to put this logic on database side(sql) but not in your application codes?

Comment: I dun get what you mean. The activate part is for the customers.. at first, there's no activate part. Subscribe, Add record. Unsubscribe, delete record. but they will ask the report who subscribed and then unsubscribed. if they want the report for this in the future, it would b easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: *(Disclaimer: this is untested code, but you should get the general idea)*

```
create procedure AddUser
    @NewUserName varchar(50)
as

    set nocount on;

    declare @SubscriberActive bit

    if exists
    (
        select *
        from YourUserTable
        where subscriber_name = @NewUserName
    )
    begin
        select @SubscriberActive = subscriber_active
        from YourUserTable
        where subscriber_name = @NewUserName

        if @SubscriberActive = 0
        begin
            update YourUserTable
            set subscriber_active = 1,
                subscriber_activedate = getdate()
            where subscriber_name = @NewUserName
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into YourUserTable(subscriber_name) -- fill in the rest of your not null fields
        values(@NewUserName)
    end
go
```

Comment: @william what else were you looking for?  This is pretty simple logic.

Comment: Yea, I know.. i am just wondering something shorter. Nvm.. i can use that logic.

Comment: @william 25ish lines of code isn't too bad, especially when it's easy to read/maintain/understand. :)